# Recargar variable dentro de un div?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tengo un buscador que según como lo rellenes debe aparecer un botón o otro, la idea es que si no introduzco uno de los filtros/campos del buscador el botón de buscar se quede en negro, os dejo como lo he hecho:

```
                    <div class="searchsubmit-wrapper">
                    <div class="submit-main-button">
                        <div id="divevento">
                        {if $selectedCat == false}
                            Selecciona almenos dos filtros
                        {else}
                        <div class="searchsubmit2">{__ 'BUSCAR'}</div>
                        <input type="submit" value="{__ 'BUSCAR'}" class="searchsubmit">
                        {/if}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

y aquí os dejo la variable:

```
{var $selectedCat = isset($_REQUEST['category']) && $_REQUEST['category'] != "" ? $_REQUEST['category'] : ''}
```

si `selectedCat` no tiene valor quiero que aparezca el mensaje de "selecciona dos filtros" que una vez funcione cambiaré por el submit pero en color gris y no seleccionable

y si selectedCat tiene valor quiero que aparezca el botón submit bien.

Hasta aquí va todo bien, el problema es que necesito que se actualice el valor de esta variable sin tener que recargar la página y he estado buscando y intentando probar cosas pero creo que ni me acerco a lo que quiero y no tengo ni idea de *ajax*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisa el inspector web que es lo que reenderiza el servidor, por lo que veo no sera posible sin refrescar la página, o bien utilizar `ajax` para mostrar lo que quieres.

Esto seria lo que mostraría el inspector web (f12)

```
<div id="divevento">
    Selecciona al menos dos filtros
</div>
```

Con una peticion `ajax` podrías consultar la variable al servidor y de esta forma te evitarías refrescar la pagina completa

**NOTA:** esto es usando `jQuery`

```
$.ajax({
  url: "url_de_la_variable",
  data: "si es necesario enviamos algo",
  success: function(data){
    //recibimos toda la información de la variable
    if(data[0].selectedCat=="true"){
      //.html() reemplazaría el texto del div y lo sustituiría por lo que le pongas dentro de .html("")
      $('#divevento').html(
        '<div class="searchsubmit2">info_data</div>'+
        '<input type="submit" value="info_data" class="searchsubmit">'
      );
    };
  },
  error: function(objXMLHttpRequest){
    console.log(objXMLHttpRequest);
  }
});
```

Comment: buenas juank, gracias por tu ayuda.  el script que pusiste tengo que añadirlo en un archivo .js a parte y despues cargarlo en el html verdad? y en "url_de_la_variable" que tengo que poner? perdona las preguntas pero no tengo ni idea de ajax ni de este tipo de scripts

Comment: puedes ponerlo en el `html` de la vista con las etiquetas `<script>$.ajax(){...}</script>` o bien como tu dices archivo aparte llamándolo de esta forma `<script src='url_del_archivo.js'><script>` en la "url_de_la_variable" puedes sustituirla por el nombre del archivo donde detecta ese cambio es decir "`archivoCambioVariable.php`"